# Max number of shared preference files?

Tags: android

I want to store some data in shared preferences files instead of sqlite for the sake of simplicity and to avoid the overhead and boilerplate of sqlite.

Is there any limit to the number (not size) of SharedPreferences files a single application can create ?

Is it safe to assume that less than a hundred files would be fine ?

Comment: `for the sake of simplicity` ... Well, it really seems you'd love to make your life **harder**!!

Comment: IMO If you need more than, say, four shared preference files, you should start to think of a SQLite database

Answer (score 1):

> All shared prefs are stored in /data/data/[package
>   name]/shared_prefs/[app name].xml, so i think there's no limit based
>   on aechitecture.
>
> I don't know practical limit but i think it's enough for you :D.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limition for sharedPrefrence file. You can save multiple file but it bad habbit. Sqlite is best option for that otherwise you can serialize and then save to it shared prefrences.

Answer (score 0):

there is no limit in Shared Preference.

its stored in /data/data/[package name]/shared_prefs/[name].xml

you can see this file if your phone is rooted

You can also use SQlite Db ,if you need to store more data use DB,because  its easy to handle data with databases

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on the free memory on device. But don't use SP for storing huge amount of data. It may crash your application sometimes.